# Live connection with web data connector

Tags: tableau-api

Is it possible to use a live connection by using the web data connector in Tableau? Or do I have always build an extract? Currently I am using the trial version and in that version the live connection option is greyed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web data connector always creates an extract. See this link for more details. https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/wdc/en-us/help.htm#WDC/wdc_phases.htm